# How to reproject EPSG:102218 with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have a raster file. ArcMap says it is in `NAD_1983_USFS_R6_Albers` (EPSG:102218).

QGIS says it is in `USER:100000 -  * Generated CRS (+proj=aea +lat_1=43 +lat_2=48 +lat_0=34 +lon_0=-120 +x_0=600000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs)`.

I assume QGIS doesn't know that coordinate system. So I can also not re-project it with QGIS, right? Is there a work around to still reproject it with QGIS?

I don't want to re-project it with ArcMap.

Comment: Have you tried? If you have the details and they're correct, as you seem to, you can probably do a warp to a new projection.

Comment: When i try warp, I don't know which Source SRS I should choose. `EPSG:102218` is not available. QGIS suggests `EPSG:9001`, which is not valid at all.

Comment: If you set it up in the warp tool in QGIS, then click the edit button, you can add your string from above in. In fact, you might see the user generated coordinate string in the top box.... I'll answer below.

Comment: If you geodata comes with a projection attached (georaster, .prj file, etc.) that is not in the EPSG catalogue QGIS will set up a custom projection called "USER:XXXXXX". This will work just like any other projection from the EPSG list, as long as the definition is correct.

Comment: Thanks guys. Your suggestion works fine. Though I am still wondering why QGIS doesn't recognize the EPSG code right away. But that's another topic.

Comment: QGIS won't recognize EPSG:102218 because this is not an official code published by EPSG. It is created by ESRI as a custom CRS. GDAL (and importing that QGIS) has added a bunch of ESRI's custom codes, but not that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GDAL Warp with the string you have above, assuming it is correct.

In QGIS, you can set it up like this:

[image: QGIS Custom Coordinate System Example]

That shows how you can do it with the warp command in gdal too, simply use -s_srs "big long projection string goes in here"